# Is there a CMaskedTextField option that enables to not only separate user input with characters, but also in separate textboxes?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jquery-mask

[image]
Im using CMaskedTextField to obtain this kind of result
[image]
However, I am actually trying to get this one

I was wondering if there was an option with CMaskedTextField that enables this feature, or in case there isnt, if anybody knows what is the most practical way in which it can be implemented. I know i could use javascript, but before i get into that im trying to squeeze Yii's provided functionalities as much as possible. Many many thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.  You need to specify the `$placeholder` property.

**Example: In your view the widget should look like this**

```
<?php $this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array(
                'mask'=>'99-9999-99',
                'name'=>'mask_tester',
                'placeholder'=>' ',
        )); ?>
```

Notice the placeholder is a space rather than default which is an underscore.  Also, if you're passing a `$model` into the form you need to strike the `$name` property and add `$model` and `$attribute` properties.

However, this widget will never give you separate input boxes.  It will always be in one input box.

Comment: Well this is as close as i can possibly get to what im looking for! Thank you very much it worked perfectly. I'll try to develop my own widget by tonight, I kinda use this feature quite often!

Comment: No problem.  Sorry it isn't 100% of what you want.  If you do make your widget you should consider putting it up on the yii site.  I'm sure more people are looking for what you are going for.